# Centos 7.6 emacsclient can't find socket

Tags: emacs, centos, emacsclient, emacs26

I followed the instructions

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files

create a emacs.service under `/etc/systemd/system/`like this

```
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/hye/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
ExecStop=/home/hye/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

then I execute:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start emacs.service
```

the emacs.service launched successfully

However when I run `emacsclient -t` in terminal, it shows:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
```

I find that if I switch to root and run `emacsclient -t` in terminal, it works well.

In fact, host name is `/tmp/emacs0/server`,
but I can't access it since it's owner is root.

```
emacsclient -t -s /tmp/emacs0/server
emacsclient: can't stat /tmp/emacs0/server: Permission denied
emacsclient: error accessing socket "/tmp/emacs0/server"
```

I have tried to add User option in emacs.service, like this

```
[Service]
User=hye
Group=hye
Type=forking
```

but systemctl can't start this service, it is always failed.

I have also tried to put emacs.service under `~/.config/systemd/user/`

but centos 7 doesn't support `systemctl --user`.

system information:

```
Centos 7.6
Emacs-26.1 manually installed
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem....

..it came down to I was using emacs-snapshot for emacs in

```
   update-alternatives --display emacs
```

..and a *different* version for emacsclient

Set it to the same version and then Good Things happened.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set emacsclient /usr/bin/emacsclient-snapshot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, right now I do not have a centos 7.6 system, I am using fedora 31, I can not testify your solution, anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: Yep! This right here. Somehow I have Emacs 25.3 in my /usr/local/bin, with its accompanying emacsclient. And that's the one found by `which`, while Emacs 27.1 is the version that's actually running on the computer. Choose the correct emacsclient, and voila! Back up and running.